# Turning text file into a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, multidimensional-array, input

I need to take a text file like the one below and create a 2d array from the numbers in it. However, it needs to be very general so that it could apply to a text file with more or fewer entries than this one.

```
1 1 11  
1 2 32  
1 4 23  
2 2 24  
2 5 45  
3 1 16  
3 2 37  
3 3 50  
3 4 79  
3 5 68  
4 4 33  
4 5 67  
1 1 75  
1 4 65  
2 1 26  
2 3 89  
2 5 74
```

This is what I have so far, but it just gives me all zeroes when I print it.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MySales11 {
   //variables
   private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
   private int numberOfEntries;
   private int [][] allSales;

   //constructor
   public MySales11 (Scanner scan) {
      //scan and find # of entries
      while (scan.hasNext()){
         String line = scan.nextLine();
         list.add(line);
      }
      //define size of AllSales array
      allSales = new int[list.size()][3];
      //populate AllSales array with list ArrayList
      for(int a = 0; a < allSales.length; a++){
         String[] tokens = list.get(a).split(" ");
         for(int b = 0; b < tokens.length; b++){
              allSales[a][b] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[b]);
         } 
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read all the lines when you wanted to create a array of size numOfEntries.

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    scan.nextLine();
    numberOfEntries++;//this reads all the lines but never stores
}
allSales = new int[numberOfEntries][3];
while (scan.hasNext()) {//input is empty
//the execution never comes here.
}
```

Now the input is empty. So it'll never add values to the array.

---

You can use an `arrayList`, dynamic - no need to calculate number of lines.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
while (scan.hasNext()) {
  String s = scan.nextLine();
  list.add(s);
}

int [][] myArray = new int[list.size()][3];

for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i)
{
 String[] tokens = list.get(i).split("\\s+");//extra spaces
 for(int j = 0; j < tokens.length; ++j)
 {
   myArray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[j]);
 } 
}
```

Comment: I feel like I'm on the verge of getting it to work. I tried your advice and am currently getting an error while trying to parse the integers and I have no clue why. I'll edit my code above to show you what I did. And thanks for the help so far!

Comment: I got it! For some reason I had to space it out with an extra space in the .split(" ") and it started working! Thank you so much!

Comment: .split("\s+") use this instead. Also accept the answer if you feel it helped.